# Rotate an entire Google chart

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, charts, google-visualization

I wanted to show my graph but in a vertical way not horizontal like show on the following image and also hide the legend if possible.

Thanks in advance for your help.

[Charts horizontal to vertical](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPZVr.png)

[Symmetry of the rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8X5d.png)

```
 google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']}); google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);


function drawBasic() {

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('number', 'X');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Dogs');

      data.addRows([
        [0, 0],   [1, 10],  [2, 23],  [3, 17],  [4, 18],  [5, 9],
        [6, 11],  [7, 27],  [8, 33],  [9, 40],  [10, 32], [11, 35],
        [12, 30], [13, 40], [14, 42], [15, 47], [16, 44], [17, 48],
        [18, 52], [19, 54], [20, 42], [21, 55], [22, 56], [23, 57],
        [24, 60], [25, 50], [26, 52], [27, 51], [28, 49], [29, 53],
        [30, 55], [31, 60], [32, 61], [33, 59], [34, 62], [35, 65],
        [36, 62], [37, 58], [38, 55], [39, 61], [40, 64], [41, 65],
        [42, 63], [43, 66], [44, 67], [45, 69], [46, 69], [47, 70],
        [48, 72], [49, 68], [50, 66],
      ]);

      var options = {
        hAxis: {
          textPosition:"none"
        },
        vAxis: {
          textPosition:"none"
        },

      };


      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'))

      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

Comment: provide your code if you want any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use chart options...

```
orientation: 'vertical'
```

and...

```
legend.position: 'none'
```

see the following working snippet...

it also demonstrates increasing the size of the `chartArea` to fill the container

which the chart will not do by default...

```
chartArea: {
  top: 6,
  right: 6,
  bottom: 6,
  left: 6,
  height: '100%',
  width: '100%'
},
```

---

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawBasic,
  packages:['corechart']
});

function drawBasic() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'X');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Y');

  data.addRows([
    [0, 0],   [1, 10],  [2, 23],  [3, 17],  [4, 18],  [5, 9],
    [6, 11],  [7, 27],  [8, 33],  [9, 40],  [10, 32], [11, 35],
    [12, 30], [13, 40], [14, 42], [15, 47], [16, 44], [17, 48],
    [18, 52], [19, 54], [20, 42], [21, 55], [22, 56], [23, 57],
    [24, 60], [25, 50], [26, 52], [27, 51], [28, 49], [29, 53],
    [30, 55], [31, 60], [32, 61], [33, 59], [34, 62], [35, 65],
    [36, 62], [37, 58], [38, 55], [39, 61], [40, 64], [41, 65],
    [42, 63], [43, 66], [44, 67], [45, 69], [46, 69], [47, 70],
    [48, 72], [49, 68], [50, 66],
  ]);

  var options = {
    chartArea: {
      top: 6,
      right: 6,
      bottom: 6,
      left: 6,
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%'
    },
    hAxis: {
      textPosition: 'none'
    },
    height: 800,
    legend: {
      position: 'none'
    },
    orientation: 'vertical',
    vAxis: {
      textPosition: 'none'
    },
    width: 200
  };

  var chart0 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div0'));
  chart0.draw(data, options);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, {
    calc: function (dt, row) {
      return {
        v: dt.getValue(row, 1) * -1,
        f: dt.getFormattedValue(row, 1),
      };
    },
    label: data.getColumnLabel(1),
    type: data.getColumnType(1)
  }]);

  var chart1 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div1'));
  chart1.draw(view, options);
}
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div0"></div>
<div id="chart_div1"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this second solution, but it is possible to have the symmetry of the result ??

Comment: I edit my question to show what I mean by symmetry :)

Comment: changed snippet above to draw two charts -- uses a DataView to set the values to the opposite sign in the DataTable -- uses object notation so that values are still displayed as the correct sign...

Comment: Thanks a lot ! :D

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this with css (and add `legend: {position: 'none'}` in the options to hide the legend)

```js
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});

google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);

function drawBasic() {

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'X');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Dogs');

  data.addRows([
    [0, 0],   [1, 10],  [2, 23],  [3, 17],  [4, 18],  [5, 9],
    [6, 11],  [7, 27],  [8, 33],  [9, 40],  [10, 32], [11, 35],
    [12, 30], [13, 40], [14, 42], [15, 47], [16, 44], [17, 48],
    [18, 52], [19, 54], [20, 42], [21, 55], [22, 56], [23, 57],
    [24, 60], [25, 50], [26, 52], [27, 51], [28, 49], [29, 53],
    [30, 55], [31, 60], [32, 61], [33, 59], [34, 62], [35, 65],
    [36, 62], [37, 58], [38, 55], [39, 61], [40, 64], [41, 65],
    [42, 63], [43, 66], [44, 67], [45, 69], [46, 69], [47, 70],
    [48, 72], [49, 68], [50, 66],
  ]);

  var options = {
    hAxis: {
      textPosition:"none"
    },
    vAxis: {
      textPosition:"none"
    },
    legend: {position: 'none'}
  };


  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'))

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```css
#chart_div{
  transform-origin: 80% 50%;
  transform:rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Great, I will do that now ! Thanks a lot ! :D                                                         Just another question, how 'transform-origin' work ?

Comment: just googlize it ;) https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform-origin.asp . Also don't forget to validate the best answer (which is @WhiteHat's one!;)

Comment: Thanks for all infos ;)